# Adding an info button to a navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

Currently my project consists of 5 tab bar controllers, each their own navigation controller, the setup is mainly done within the app delegate and all of this is done through code, not nib files. I have a class for every tabbar/nav controllers.

My goal in this problem is to code a `UIBarButtonItem` on the navbar within one of my tabbarcontrollers.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pushToInfoController)];
```

I basically use that piece of code to display the button within my HomeView (tab bar 1).

Now, when the user presses the button, I want to push to a new view controller where I can display info on the use of the app and other instructions on how to use it, this isnt really important, what is, is getting the button to do what it needs to do.

I plan on creating a function `-(void) pushToInfoController` to be the selector function but i really dont know how to go about this.

Comment: It's a convention to put tab bar controller inside navigation controller so that you can use only one navigation controller only.

Comment: Then what is the difficulty in it? You have navigation controler inside that tab no? You can just push the new viewController normally...

Comment: yeah sorry.... i was able to figure it out... DURP!!!! Thank you for your feedback